# Running into errors with Tensorflow/pandas sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I'm currently setting up a TF module with Pandas. It has run into a few errors but the first one is that 'data' isn't defined. In addition NameError: name 'train' is not defined. I tried running def to each but then throw multiple syntax errors.

```
import tensorflow as myTensorFlow
mysession = myTensorFlow.Session()
import pandas
dataset = pandas.read_csv('linear.csv')
dataset.shape
(1000, 5)
data.columns
Index([u'Classification', u'DGMLEN', u'IPLEN', u'TTL', u'IP'],dtype='object')
y, X = train['Classification'], train[['DGMLEN', 'IPLEN', 'IP']].fillna(0)
X_Modeltrain, X_Modeltest, y_Modeltrain, y_Modeltest = train_Modeltest_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=29)
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_Modeltrain, y_Modeltrain)
print accuracy_score(y_Modeltest, lr.predict(X_Modeltest))
```

Comment: You loaded the df as `dataset`, therefore `train` isn't defined, do you want to name it `train` instead?

Comment: It seems you need `y, X = dataset['Classification'],dataset[['DGMLEN', 'IPLEN', 'IP']].fillna(0)`

Comment: I will try to rename it train (thanks for pointing that out @EdChum @jezrael) but if I rename it, along with replacing with y, X = dataset['Classification'],dataset[['DGMLEN', 'IPLEN', 'IP']].fillna(0) it throws an error for index not being defined

Comment: @EdChum would index have to be defined within the data file?

Comment: Can't say without seeing your csv, `read_csv` has an option to consider one of the columns as the index ( or multi-index) if you don't specify it, it will generate one for you, I don't see why this would matter here. You need to post some sample lines from your csv and complete and typo free code that generates this error

Comment: @EdChum that could be why, at the moment I'm just using a demo CSV since I still have to capture data and write it to the CSV. That would make sense then for the error since it's format is missing currently in the CSV, correct?